# Internationalizing a Django class-based generic view (CreateView)?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-generic-views

I am using Django 1.9 [class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/), for example [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView).  When I visit the "create" page, some parts are translated (into French in my example), so I know my config and wiring is correct, but the form fields (auto-named by the view) are not (i.e. form.as_p).

How can I get form fields to be used from my translations file?  (For example, "Name" is a field, already translated, but not picked up by the form.as_p).

One answer is to list out the fields individually in the template with {% trans %} tags.  I was hoping to avoid that.

My example is similar to the one in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), so let me repeat that example here.  First, code:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
```

Then display template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Lazy Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation):

> This is essential when calls to these functions are located in code paths that are executed at module load time.
>
> This is something that can easily happen when defining `models`, `forms` and `model forms`, because Django implements these such that their fields are actually `class-level` attributes.

So, if you have a form, you can use `ugettext_lazy` to translate:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyThing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(help_text=_('This is the help text'))
```

> You can mark names of `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField` or `OneToOneField` relationship as translatable by using their `verbose_name` options:

```
class MyThing(models.Model):
    kind = models.ForeignKey(
        ThingKind,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='kinds',
        verbose_name=_('kind'),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case setting/importing: ugettext_lazy and verbose_name as you wrote, was the right decision.